# "request" in " request.getRequestURI();"

Tags: java, url, request

I am trying to print the browser URL using Java. I have come across codes where they have used "request.getRequestURI();" to retrieve the URL. What is this "request" in "request.getRequestURI();" ? How do we define it? Can i get an example of a code with "request" defined?

Comment: It's a parameter to the servlet spec's request handlers. It's defined in by JEE.

Comment: Be careful if your app server is behind a web server and/or proxy server. The `host:port` portion of the URL may not be the same value that the browser sees!

Answer (score 0):

The request object retrieves the values that the client browser passed to the server during an HTTP request such as headers, cookies or parameters associated with the request. Among the most common use of the request object is to obtain parameter or query string values. The following demo illustrates how to use the request object for parsing form data. - See more at: http://www.gulland.com/courses/jsp/objects#sthash.zigrGeiE.dpuf

The request object is an instance of `HttpServletRequest`. The request object is implicitly defined in jsp pages. It is also a parameter in the `doGet` and `doPost` method of an HttpServlet

So in a servlet, you'll have something like:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
```

and in a jsp page, you can access an object, lets say the firstName string, attached to the request with expression language:

```
<p>${request.firstName}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an HttpServletRequest object.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html.

Normally it is passed in to a method on your controller.